# Export Project from Netbeans as Installer

Tags: java, netbeans

After having made a project in Netbeans, is there a way to export it as an installer? It doesn't need to REALLY be an installer, just something that a regular user can put on their PC and start using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Ant Installer](http://antinstaller.sourceforge.net/index.html). You can make the creation of the installer the last step in your build process or alternatively just make it a build target that you run.